# How to generate SVG on a server using Fabric.js data saved in database

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, canvas, fabricjs

I am using Fabric.js as canvas framework and I am saving all objects rendered by Fabric.js in database as a serialized string my question is how to form SVG from those saved objects at server side by using PHP only.

Is there any standard xml template for generating SVG image?

Comment: please help me with this

Comment: did you try canvas.toSVG() ? This returns a svg xml template which you can load any where.